# Deterministic Commitment Schemes

Tags: commitments

Are there any deterministic commitment schemes? What are their security properties, if so? Most ones I see are randomized.

Comment: If most ones you see are randomized, you must have seen deterministic ones, no?

Comment: What do you mean by a "_deterministic_" commitment scheme?

Answer (score 2):

We can use a simple cryptographic hash function as a commitment.
But it allows for an adversary to guess low entropy values.

If by deterministic commitment you want a public function that receives only the value we are commiting to and no randomness or other input. It means if the possible value to be committed can be guessed with non negligible probability an adversary can verify their guess independently and discover the secret value prematurely.

To prevent this we add randomness.